# AS3 Class Function Scope

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

If I have 2 classes and the first extends the second, how can the second class call a static function from the first?

```
package p1 {
    class a {
        static function a1() {
            //do soemthing
        }
    }

    class b extends a {
        static function b1() {
            //do something else
        }
    }
}
```

```
a.a1(); // this works
b.a1(); // this doesn't work
b.b1(); //this works
```

Comment: whooops the method is static.

Comment: ah... i thought a & b were instances of class A and B. I'm not sure if you can inherit static functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When "B extends A" - this actually is not the same as "class B has all methods and properties of A". Not class, but object of class B implements all properties and methods, defined in class A. When you call a static method or property - you deal with classes but not objects (it looks very similar to namespaces usage).

ADDED:
The only way solve your task is to override a1(args) in class B and to call super.a1(args) inside... 1 string of code. But it seems to me, that you have a software architect problem if it's not possible to avoid such kind of usage.

Comment: This answer is correct. To expand a tad, when you call a method on an *instance* of class b, if that method doesn't exist then Flash will check class a. But when you call static methods, you call them via a (global) reference to the qualified class name, which is not something that has any kind of inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Makes sense. Not what I wanted to hear but I can deal with it.

Answer (score -1):

Use super to call the parent method.

```
super.b1();
```

EDIT: Ok, looking at what you wrote, I think you need to set the scope of a1 to be public or protected.

Comment: b1 is in the subclass b, and if it's extending a, it should inherit a's functions and be able to call them normally.